# Would using mutagen-compose be better than a multistage docker build?

Tags: docker, performance, hadoop-yarn, mutagen

Using MacOS, I have a docker compose that uses three services in the following way

```
services:
  service_1:
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/usr/src/app/apps
      - ./packages:/usr/src/app/packages\
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  service_2:
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/usr/src/app/apps
      - ./packages:/usr/src/app/packages
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  service_3:
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/usr/src/app/apps
      - ./packages:/usr/src/app/packages
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Current Dockerfile:

```
FROM node as builder

COPY . /app

RUN yarn install

FROM node

ARG app_name

COPY --from=builder /app /app

WORKDIR /app/$app_name

RUN yarn start
```

Would it be more performant to use a builder in the dockerfile or to use something like mutagen or an NFS mount? I have read about Yarn/NPM installs taking significantly longer in containers on MacOS and this has led to some confusion about whether my use case could be increased by changing my volumes to nfs/mutagen synced.

Comment: You should delete all of the `volumes:`.  This will use the code built into the Docker images, which is more reproducible, and avoids the performance penalty of bind mounts on MacOS.

Comment: @DavidMaze Of course! I'm not even making use of the mount points am I?

Comment: If I could upvote your comment I would - that's exactly what I needed to know thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Docker's standard model is that the application code is built into immutable images.  You shouldn't normally need to distribute or inject the code separately from what's built into an image.  In the example you show above, I would normally expect to see the builder `RUN` in the Dockerfile, and to not have the separate `volumes:` mounts you show.

Performance-wise, there are known issues with bind mounts on non-Linux platforms.  Some of the workarounds using an NFS service instead of Docker Desktop's native filesystem handler will be a little faster, but not as fast as using the local filesystem.  Using code built into an image avoids these performance issues entirely.

```yaml
services:
  service_1:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        app_name: app1
    # but no volumes:
```